# Reading configuration settings in .NET Core 2.0 library

Tags: c#, .net, .net-standard

I have a library I am converting from .NET 4.6.1 to .NET Standard 2.0.

I'm having a problem with configuration settings. In our old library, we are able to access configurations settings very simply using `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`. I understand there is no direct replacement for that namespace in .NET Standard, but is there a way to read such information. I suppose I could create a singleton in the library, load all the configuration settings from a text file and use that class to access all the config settings. But I am looking for an easier path here.

I know I can pass the settings in via dependency injection to my classes from the consuming application, but there are internal classes that are never accessed directly that also need these configuration settings.

Comment: documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration

Comment: This article should help: http://benfoster.io/blog/net-core-configuration-legacy-projects

Comment: @Nkosi - the link you provided should be the answer.

Comment: Until you move to the new configuration model, you could use the `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` NuGet package

Answer (score -2):

Please try like this.

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json", true, true)
    .AddInMemoryCollection();
var configuration = builder.Build();
var value = configuration.GetSection(key).Value
```

Comment: The ConfigurationBuilder in 2.0 does not support the .AddJsonFile function